# Will urdf_tools (with its arm_kinematics package) be promoted to a first-class stack?

Tags: ros, kinematics, ik, arm-kinematics

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've recently started to use the [urdf_tools](http://www.ros.org/wiki/urdf_tools) stack for the [arm_kinmatics](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_kinematics) package.

I'm wondering if this is in line to become a first-class stack that will be placed in the repositories.

- Is urdf_tools (with arm_kinematics) slated to become a first-class?
- If not, is there an alternative to urdf_tools/arm_kinematics that I should be using instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11316/will-urdf_tools-(with-its-arm_kinematics-package)-be-promoted-to-a-first-class-stack?/) by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2743 on 2011-09-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I suggest you check out this tutorial -

- [Automatically Generating Arm Navigation Configurations/Planning Description Configuration Wizard](http://www.ros.org/wiki/arm_navigation/Tutorials/Automatically%20Generating%20Arm%20Navigation%20Configurations/Planning%20Description%20Configuration%20Wizard) .

The wizard will auto-configure generic IK (basically the same thing provided by the arm_navigation package) while also auto-generating necessary configuration files for planning and trajectory filtering.  It will also allow you to visualize your robot model in rviz, use the planning components visualizer to plan paths, and then use the warehouse viewer to do even more things.

If there are specific features available in urdf_tools or arm_kinematics that we should include in arm_navigation then let me know.

---

Originally posted by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) with karma: 2031 on 2011-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [egiljones](https://answers.ros.org/users/82/egiljones/) on 2011-09-26**:
I don't know all of what it does, but if you are primarily using it for kinematics then the wizard should supplant that and make it collision-aware.  The joint_state_publisher seems useful, but you can probably use that alongside arm_navigation.

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2011-09-26**:
Do you know if the code generation from the wizard is meant to completely replace urdf_tools/arm_kinematics?